# Combine two json files to give a set of variables to use in Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have seen lots of posts online about how to use a set of variables defined in a file using a require statement.

I want to know how I can use two files.

For example, in pseudo...

```
gulp --env=prod

if (env):
  defaultConfig = require('./config/default.json')
  envConfig = require('./config/prod.json')
  config = combine(defaultConfig, envConfig)
else:
  config = require('./config/default.json')

// Now i can access everything like so...
console.log(config.name)
console.log(config.minify)
```

This keeps by config DRY and also means I don't have to create a new file for every environment I have.

I'm new to Gulp but i thought this would be a common requirement however, Google hasn't turned up anything for having defaults merged with env specific settings.

Do i need to write a node module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`yargs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) to parse command line arguments and [`extend`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extend) to combine the two config objects:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var argv = require('yargs').argv;
var extend = require('extend');

var config = extend(
  require('./config/default.json'),
  (argv.env) ? require('./config/' + argv.env + '.json') : {}
);

gulp.task('default', function() {
  console.log(config);
});
```

Running `gulp --env=prod` will print the combined config, while simply running `gulp` will print the default config.

Comment: Thanks Sven.  Two further questions...

1. How can I handle the error that occurs if I reference a config file that doesn't exist? E.g.

    gulp --env=idontexist

    Error: Cannot find module '../config/bla.json'

Is there a way I can capture this and print something more friendly like "Config file bla.json doesn't exist"?

I've added my second question as an edit to the question so I had space.

Comment: Don't ask unrelated follow-up questions in comments or edits. What you're asking doesn't really have much to do with your original question (combining json files). You should create new questions for that.

Comment: This actually doesn't work as expected as properties are copied over rather than extended.  For example:
   
    // default.json   
    { "styles": { "src": "my/src", "dest": "my/dest", minify": false } }

    // prod.json
    { "styles": { minify": true } }

will result in:

    { "styles": { minify": true } }

rather than the expected:

    { "styles": { "src": "my/src", "dest": "my/dest", minify": true } }

Comment: Nope, works as expected. Seems what you're after is actually a recursive [`merge`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge).

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with **ES6** function `Object.assign`:

```
gulp --env=prod

if (env):
  defaultConfig = JSON.parse(require('./config/default.json'))
  envConfig = JSON.parse(require('./config/prod.json'))
  config = Object.assign(defaultConfig, envConfig)
else:
  config = JSON.parse(require('./config/default.json'))

// Now i can access everything like so...
console.log(config.name)
console.log(config.minify)
```

ES6 is supported in Node so you can use it whenever you want.

EDIT: If you have older versions of Node, you can use [`extend`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extend) like [Sven Schoenung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5892036/sven-schoenung) suggest.

Comment: Depends on what version of node you use. Node 0.x (which is still [widely used](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2015/12/15/nodejs-version-usage-in-commercial-projects-2015-edition.html)) doesn't support `Object.assign()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function :

```
 function combine(a,b){
    var temp0 = JSON.stringify(a);
    var temp1 = temp0.substring(0, temp0.length-1);
    var temp2 = (JSON.stringify(b)).substring(1);
    var temp3 = temp1 + "," + temp2;
    return JSON.parse(temp3);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. `a` is an object, not a string, so `a.length` is `undefined`.